# Label controls added in code to a Panel are not displayed

Tags: c#, panel

Why not `lable_2` and `lable_3` are not displayed?

[image: Screenshot of GUI]

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int X = 153;
    int Y = 34;
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {

        Panel pnl = new Panel();
        pnl.SuspendLayout();
        pnl.Location = new Point(X, Y);
        pnl.Name = "pnl"+i;
        pnl.Size = new Size(200, 57);
        pnl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Location = new Point(X - 100, Y - 17);
        lbl.Name = "lbl" + i;
        lbl.Size = new Size(75, 23);
        lbl.Text = "lable_" +i;

        pnl.Controls.Add(lbl);
        pnl.ResumeLayout(false);

        this.Controls.Add(pnl);

        Y = Y + 95;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please do no post images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: check the value of Y for the last 2 labels. The height of panel is 57 and Y-17 is more than 57.

Comment: i got it, the label is in the panel so its location won't change,edit  lbl.Location = new Point(X - 100, Y-20); -> lbl.Location = new Point(50, 20);

Answer (score 0):

The Y-position of the 2nd and 3rd labels is outside the bounds of the panel. Instead of giving the location, you can use the Dock property of the Label.

```
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "Label test";
    lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Comment: thanks you so much; i changed lbl.Location = new Point(X-100, Y-20); -> lbl.Location = new Point(50, 20); It was okay